# Stop list item stacking in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a bottom navbar (footer) in Twitter Bootstrap to contain some social media links:

[image: NavBar1]

There's a break-point at which the unordered list items (`li`) become stacked vertically rather than horizontally:

[image: NavBar2]

I can see this behaviour is desirable for using the navbar with headings (I'm using it on my top navbar), but since I'm just using this bottom one for icons, I don't want them stacked vertically as there's plenty of width for them to line-up horizontally down to a mobile screen.

How can I disable this behaviour on just my bottom navbar?

I'd also be interested to know whether the phone number and icon I have in my left-side nav items could disappear when the width of the device is less than the width of the phone number and social media icons.

Bootstrap version is 3.3.2.

**Update**: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0jqssmmb/

Comment: If you post your css as well, that can help a great deal. It's always best to create a jsfiddle of your work and post that with your question.

Comment: @RobR I've added a fiddle update to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there were 3 issues I needed to solve:

1. **Display the social media icons horizontally rather than stacked vertically when window width falls below a certain size.**

As @fructurj pointed out this can be fixed by adding `display: inline-block` to the `navbar-nav>li` selector in css. However, this would affect all navbars; I only want my footer navbar to behave this way. To do this, simply add a custom class at the same `ul` level as navbar-nav in your footer html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-custom">
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/maneevent6" target="_blank" title="@manevent6"><img src="\img\icons\twitter\Twitter_logo_blue.png" class="tw-logo"></a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then apply `display: inline-block` to only that selector in your css media query:

```
.navbar-nav>li {             /* <- this affects all navbars */
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-custom>li {          /* <- this affects just my footer navbar */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will cause the social media icons to align horizontally rather than stack vertically, which is what I'm after. Unfortunately though, the icons will become left-aligned, which brings us to the 2nd issue...

2. **Re-align social media icons in footer nav-bar**

The social media icons lose their horizontal alignment once inline-block has been applied. To set a new horizontal alignment I surrounded the `ul` that houses my social media icons in a new `div` with my own custom class "img-inline":

```
<div class="img-inline">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-custom">
        <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/maneevent6" target="_blank" title="@manevent6"><img src="\img\icons\twitter\Twitter_logo_blue.png" class="tw-logo"></a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then picked this up in my css media query and applied `text-align: center;` as that was my preferred alignment at this screen width:

```
.img-inline {
    text-align: center;
}
```

3. **Hide the telephone number in the footer when window width falls below a certain size.**

Finally, I wanted to hide the telephone number I put in the footer. To do this I added a custom class "navbar-hide" to the `ul` housing the telephone number:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar-hide">
    <li>
        <p id="Telephone"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> 01999 999999</p>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Then picked this up in my css media query by applying `display: none !important;`:

```
.navbar-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Here's the fiddle of the updated code (original is the question): http://jsfiddle.net/0jqssmmb/3/

Comment: I had to do a  'float:left' instead of 'float:none' to make it appear correctly for IE11.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:inline-block` at your list item in media query:

```
 .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful and referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help **Bootstrap 4** users, where i faced a very similar issue:

Add a navbar-expand `navbar-expand` class to your `<nav>` element at the very top of your navbar declaration.

Example from the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

The docs are also explicitly stating this:

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that, when I apply `display: inline-block;` contents of list break out. So if you want to put your list looks fine you need to do

```
.navbar-nav>li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: how many contents you have %;
    }
```

If you have 3, then `width:33%;`

Comment: what is the new information in your answer? `width:...`? Was that asked in the question?

Comment: I just want list contents look fine. If I didn't add `width`, the list contents put together.